# dailymotion javascript SDK login redirect_uri mismatch

Tags: javascript, authentication, sdk, dailymotion-api

My problem is: When I try login of Dailymotion with javascript SDK

```
Dm.login( my_callback, {
    scope: my_scopes, 
    redirect_uri: my_url, 
    response_type: "code" 
});
```

The PopUp is open and does not load the Daylimotion login page, returning my page redirect_uri with url params error:

> `**[my_url]?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=This+%60redirect_uri%27+isn%27t+allowed+by+%60client_id%27+configuration.&state=dmauth_XXXXXXXXX**`

But in my Dailymotion configuration, the `return url` is 
exactly equal my `redirect_uri` sent by param to `Dm.login`

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dailymotion API has changed and no longer accepts the `#` character in `return_url` and my URL contained a # and so did not work.

Answer (score 0):

that sounds like the same problem as [Dailymotion Callback URL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046405/dailymotion-callback-url-error/32091404)

You should make sure that `redirect_uri` matches the "callback url" you defined when creating the api key at http://www.dailymotion.com/settings/developer . It not matching, it will trigger the error you mentioned.