# Dailymotion Callback URL Error

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to connect to the Data-API by using the PHP-SDK.

I have configured an API-Key. But when trying to connect an exception is thrown. Message:

> This `redirect_uri' isn't allowed by`client_id' configuration.

I suppose that somehow the callback URL is not correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `redirect_uri`, if is stated at https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php/blob/master/Dailymotion.php#L196 that:

"if using authorization grant type, this key can be provided. If omitted, the current URL will be used. Make sure this value stays the same before the user is redirect to the authorization page and after the authorization page redirects to this URI (the token server will change this)."

You should also make sure that this value matches the "callback url" you defined when creating the api key at http://www.dailymotion.com/settings/developer . It not matching, it will trigger the error you mentioned.